# Delete JSON objects within a certain

Tags: python, json

I have multiple JSON files (about 700) containing lists of GPS coordinates. I plan to animate those coordinates but only the ones within a specific range. How do I determine which coordinates are within the range of interest and how would I delete all the others using a python script?

```
 [
    {
        "snapshot_id": "1628985627",
        "altitude": "37000",
        "heading": "98",
        "latitude": "40.58775",
        "longitude": "50.52875",
        "radar_id": "42728",
        "speed": "561",
        "squawk": "5160"
    },
    {
        "snapshot_id": "1628985691",
        "altitude": "37000",
        "heading": "99",
        "latitude": "40.56199",
        "longitude": "50.74123",
        "radar_id": "2027",
        "speed": "561",
        "squawk": "5160"
    },
    {........
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your actual question?  How to edit a file?  How to remove items from a dictionary?  How to remove items from a list?  How to determine if coordinates are within a given range?

Comment: Try to come up with a procedure that you could perform yourself. You know what you have / where you are and you know what you'd like to have instead / where you want to go. How would you go about getting there by hand? How can you perform those steps in Python, or how can you put bits of Python you know about together to automate the procedure? If any of the activities in particular is unclear, or you have trouble getting it to work, make your question specific to that (as @JohnGordon indicates)

Comment: @Grismar to be honest I've close to zero knowledge of Python. what I need to do is determine what coordinates in the JSON  are within a given range and delete all the others

Comment: That's OK, SO is here to help programmers of all skill levels - however, it's not here to write your code for you, so it's generally best to provide a sample of what you've tried so far. If your question is "I have no idea where to start", you should probably watch or read a few tutorials on Python in general, but if you have something very basic but you don't really know how to take the next step, share the code you have and explain what the next problem is you're trying to solve.